# Trying to get the text written inside a TinyMCE textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm trying to get the text written inside a **TinyMCE** `textarea`. I have the code below. The TinyMCE text area is showed but the alert is not even showed. Why?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js'></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/home/javiergarcia/Scaricati/jari/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "textareas",
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('form').submit(function() {
                    //alert("fasdfs");
                    alert(tinyMCE.get('#jander').getContent());
                });
            });
        </script>
        <form method="post" action="somepage">
            <textarea name="content" id="jander" style="width:100%"></textarea> 
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Regards

Javier

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Why don't you simply use `tinymce.get('jander').getContent();` (tinymce in lowercases!) ?

Comment: Thanks, just removing the '#' before jander, it works, because the sharp character (#) is used in jQuery selectors and has nothing to do with tinyMCE.get()

Comment: Nice! Worked here too, for Wordpress!

Answer (score 11):

You should simply request the value of the original textarea control.

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave(false, true);
$('#jander').val();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require the TinyMCE jQuery plugin?

Comment: @Brian, thanks but it's not working..@Dunhamzzz I added the jquery.tinymce.js file but it still doesn't work..

Comment: @Dunhamzzz: Not that I'm aware of, the tinyMCE plugin is designed to hide the original textarea but keep the value of it synced with the rich text content of the tinyMCE editor. Therefore the current rich text value should always be available to be requested from the source element.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz: Remember, there is also a tinymce function that needs to be called to "save" the content back to the original element. I don't have the documentation in front of me to check though.

Comment: @Dunhammzzz: Give me five minutes, I've used jquery tinymce loads of times, I'll double check one of my projects.

Comment: @Dunhammzzz: Using the jquery tinymce plugin you must call tinyMCE.triggerSave(false, true); to ensure the rich content is sent back to the dom element before retrieving the value.

Comment: No need to trigger the save if you use the plugin properly, see my answer.

Comment: I am trying to work TinyMCE into a large professional project I am working on. In one spot we need to have multiple instances in table rows that are draggable. However, when you begin dragging one of the rows the content that is in the TinyMCE iFrame (whether it was loaded with the page or altered by the user) disappears. Once you drop the row the content is still gone but re-appears upon page refresh/reload. Is there a way to get the TinyMCE iFrame to preserve its content without needing to do a page reload? I have an example here:

http://cmzmedia.com/tinymce/examples/simple.html locked down

Answer (score 2):

Once you've included the TinyMCE jQuery plugin, you assign the editor to a variable and can then operate any jQuery function on it:

```
var wysiwyg = $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce(tinymce_settings);
```

Then to get the contents you can just fetch `wysiwyg.html();`

Also, see the [TinyMCE jQuery documentation](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php) for other manipulation techniques.

Answer (score 1):

As someone told me, the sharp character (#) is used in jQuery selectors and has nothing to do with tinyMCE.get(). So with this line below works ok.

```
alert(tinyMCE.get('jander').getContent());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one....

**$.trim(tinymce.get('jander').getContent());**