# how send tinymce content using jquery method post

Tags: jquery, post, serialization, tinymce, html-entities

I had a form.

like this

```
<form id=form ><input type='text' name='input1'  ><textarea name='text' ></textarea></form>
```

when I do this

```
var $dados = $("#form").serialize()
```

I get all the values, to send via jquery post like this

```
       $.ajax({
            url: "action.php",
            data:  $dados,
            type: 'POST',
            timeout: 6000,
            success: function (retorno) {

            }
        });
```

The beginning of the problem is, my textarea is a TinyMCE, and I get the val using this

```
 $("#form").find('textarea').each(function(){
        $dados = $dados + "&" + $(this).attr('name') + "=" +  tinyMCE.get( $(this).attr('id') ).getContent();

    });
```

My variable $dados is something likes this

```
field=value & filed2 = value ....
```

Now the problem..

when I put a text like this

"Olá mundão"

My value of the TinyeMCE is (whit the spaces to show ) Ol & #xE1; Mund &#xE3 ;o

The value is a value with HTML entity

So, I have this particular caracter "&" in the tinyMCE value.

and my variable $dados become like this

```
input1=value & input2 = val & ue
```

This particular caracter makes mess with my tinyMCE value,

So someone can help me?

Comment: can u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430543/trying-to-get-the-text-written-inside-a-tinymce-textarea

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use something like this to generate your $dados object?
There is no need to build your data as a html ajax GET Parameter string.

```
var $dados = {};
$("#form").find('textarea').each(function(){
    $dados[$(this).attr('name')] = tinyMCE.get($(this).attr('id')).getContent();
});
```